# How increase visibility on my answer to my own question

Tags: discussion, downvotes, upvotes, self-answer

Let say one asks a question and another guy gives a wrong answer (because he didn't understand fully the question or because he didn't test the result). If, after some researches and tests, the OP finds out the correct answer and wants to share his efforts with the community, he can answer his own question and accept it.

A problem comes when the other guy's answer has been up-voted. In that situation, the correct answer is left down and the incorrect answer is kept on top.

How should the OP handle this situation? He cannot up-vote his own question, neither down-vote the other answer (if he has less than 125 reputation), and if no-one pays attention and up-vote the correct answer, the incorrect answer stays on top, making the correct answer more difficult to reach for anyone who would face this question in the future.

Comment: You handle it like any other wrong answer / right answer situation. You leave it to the community to vote on both.

Comment: Isn't that their own problem though, that they don't make use of all posted answers?

Comment: improved the title of the question… because I didn't expect to find a way to up-vote my own answers ...

Comment: the problem is that sometimes it can be the newbies's problem… that doesn't have a stack-exchange account and just reads the answers.

Comment: Please help me improve the question (if you think it is not well written) or link me to a possible duplicate, instead of down voting it without explanation.

Comment: Voting on Meta is a little different; it can also be used to express disagreement with the position taken by the OP. Don't take it too personally.

Comment: okay, so an answer to my question is « I should not take position » ? BTW, where do I take position?

Comment: Not necessarily, just that others disagree with that there is a problem here that needs to be solved any more than what we already have.

Comment: clearly, that's what the community thinks. @MartijnPieters Please assemble this into an answer.

Comment: The problem here is not having enough patience.  Come back in a year or so.

Comment: … when the question will be obsolete because it willl concern an obsolete hardware/software… thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 9):

You can't vote for your own content - nor should we consider adding this feature.

What you can do is:

1. Accept your own answer - it won't stick to the question but that tick means something.
2. If you have enough reputation, down-vote the incorrect answer. This shows that it's wrong.
3. Leave a comment on the answer explaining why it's incorrect.

Beyond that you have to leave it to other users to cast their votes as they see fit.

Comment: 1 and 3 are done …I cannot down-vote the other answer

Comment: improved the title of the question… because I didn't expect to find a way to up-vote my own answers ...

Comment: why can't you down-vote the other answer?

Comment: not enouh reputation

Comment: @Jav eh?? as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), you need only `125` reputation to be able to cast a downvote.....then?

Comment: on `unix.stackexchange.com` I have only 79, but anyway, the OP doesn't have to be me, it's a general question.

Comment: updated the question to specify the fact that the OP cannot downvote the other answer(s)

Comment: @Jav you should be asking this on http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/ then or http://meta.stackexchange.com if it's a multi-site issue.

Comment: It is a general question (see update on the question about an OP having less than 125 rep).

Comment: @Jav then it should be on meta.stackexchange :)